# 2-Way SSL authentication and request authorization

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl

I am starting to develop a RESTful API (with WCF) which will be working in 2Way SSL authentication - client side certifications and server side certification.

As I understand, there will be no need for password/username because the client is already authenticated by the client-side certificate.

My problem is that some of the exposed methods should be restricted to specific clients only.

So, I also need some form of authorization. I thought about using a secret key which will be supplied to clients which are authorized of specific functions, but then I realized that this clients will already be having client-side certificates which can possibly be used for authorization.

Is there any way to get the name of the currently used client-side certificate in a programmatic way and then authorize by the certificate name?

somethine like this:

```
string clientCertificate = CertificateAuthority.GetCurrentCertificate;
if (Authorize(clientCertificate))
     doSomething()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are such methods, most noticeable the [X509Certificate2.GetNameInfo Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.getnameinfo).
(BTW, [Dominick Baier](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/05/13/fluent-api-for-the-x-509-certificate-store/) has an excellent [fluent API extension](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel) for that)

However, I think you should take a look at [Claims-Based Identity](http://claimsid.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=An%20Introduction%20to%20Claims%20%28English%29&referringTitle=Home) which will give you a much simplified code architecture.

Comment: thanks for the method, exactly what I was looking for. About the claims-based identity, it looks like kind of an overkill... I think its for more complex systems...

Answer (score 0):

The identity of the certificate holder is in the SubjectDN of the certificate.

The remainder, the authorization part, is application-dependent and varies with your architecture too. For example, if you are using LDAP you would lookup that user's roles.